# Why does parent class pointer has wrong data when casted from child pointer to parent pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++17, visual-studio-2022, data-integrity

Here is the class hierarchy that I have.

```
class EventA {/* adds itself to list */};
class EventB {/* adds itself to list */};
class EventC {/* adds itself to list */};
class EventD {/* adds itself to list */};

class EventE {/* adds itself to list */};
class EventF {/* adds itself to list */};
class EventG {/* adds itself to list */};
class EventH {/* adds itself to list */};

class Component : public EventA, public EventB, public EventC, public EventD {
    // Propeties and functions
    bool sentinel;
};

class CustomComponent : public Component {
    // Propeties and functions
};

class UserComponent : public CustomComponent, public EventE, public EventF, public EventG, public EventH {
    // Propeties and functions
};
```

I have a list of each type: `EventE`, `EventF`, `EventG`, `EventH`. They are added to the list through the constructor when I create the `UserComponent` object. The problem that I am running into is that when I iterate through the list of `EventE`, `EventF`, `EventG` and `EventH`, when I cast the pointer from either `EventE`, `EventF`, `EventG` or `EventH` to `Component*` some of the properties are not correct when interpreted as such a pointer. For example, sometimes my `bool sentinel` value will be `true(216)` when they are supposed to be `false`. My suspicion is that when I convert the pointer, it does not offset the memory to match the class hierarchy that I have laid out. In other words, I think it is not reading from correct memory address. Is anyone familiar with this issue? My problem is at system design level, so any off-topic solution, or any solution that has a different approach are welcome.

**Response to Requested Minimal Example**

This code is a minimal example of the problem that I am having. I provided it as requested in the comment section.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class EventA {
    public:
        char a;

        EventA() {
            a = 'a';
        }
        ~EventA() {

        }
};
class EventB {
    public:
        char b;
        
        EventB() {
            b = 'b';
        }
        ~EventB() {

        }
};
class EventC {
    public:
        char c;

        EventC() {
            c = 'c';
        }
        ~EventC() {

        }
};
class EventD {
    public:
        char d;

        EventD() {
            d = 'd';
        }
        ~EventD() {

        }
};

class EventE {
    public:
        char e;
        
        EventE() {
            e = 'e';
        }
        ~EventE() {

        }
};
class EventF {
    public:
        char f;

        EventF() {
            f = 'f';
        }
        ~EventF() {

        }
};
class EventG {
    public:
        char g;

        EventG() {
            g = 'g';
        }
        ~EventG() {

        }
};
class EventH {
    public:
        char h;

        EventH() {
            h = 'h';
        }
        ~EventH() {

        }
};

class Component : public EventA, public EventB, public EventC, public EventD {
    public:
        int customValue;

        Component() {
            customValue = 1000;
        }
        ~Component() {

        }
};

class CustomComponent : public Component {
    public:
        int customComponentValue;

        CustomComponent() {
            customComponentValue = 2000;
        }
        ~CustomComponent() {

        }
};

class UserComponent : public CustomComponent, public EventE, public EventF, public EventG, public EventH {
    public:
        int userComponentValue;

        UserComponent() {
            userComponentValue = 3000;
        }
        ~UserComponent() {

        }
};

int main() {
    UserComponent userComponent = UserComponent();
    EventE* ptrEventE = (EventE*)&userComponent;
    Component* ptrComponent = (Component*)ptrEventE;
    cout << ptrComponent->customValue << endl;
}
```

If you go into debug mode and inspect the value of `ptrComponent` you will see exactly what I am talking about. Note that the casting that I made is exactly what is going on at different points of my system. That is why I did it the way I did.

Comment: It should work as expected, unless you're using `reinterprete_cast` or cast through `void*`, these know nothing about multiple inheritance. Both `static_cast` and C-style cast should work. Please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, try compiling with Address Sanitizer or running with Valgrind to rule out at least some memory access errors.

Comment: I am casting like this ```Component* component = (Component*)eventEptr;``` I will provide a minimal example in a minute.

Comment: That is C-style cast, should work as long as `eventEptr` is a pointer to one of `EventA`..`EventH`. But I'd replace it with `static_cast<Component*>(eventEptr)` just to be sure.

Comment: I provided the minimal example that you requested. You should be able to replicate it. Go into debug mode and inspect the properties of ```ptrComponent```. It shows 3000 instead of 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caught if you use `static_cast` instead of a C-style cast:

```
a.cpp: In function 'int main()':
a.cpp:134:31: error: invalid 'static_cast' from type 'EventE*' to type 'Component*'
  134 |     Component* ptrComponent = static_cast<Component*>(ptrEventE);
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

`EventE` is not a base of `Component`, so the compiler does not know how the two are connected. In your case, they're connected by the common derived `UserComponent`, by there may be other common derived classes with different layouts as well, so it's of no help. `static_cast` throws an error in that case, C-style cast just does `reinterpret_cast` and assumes that no pointer modifications are needed.

Two ways to fix: either make `Component` derive from `EventE` as well or cast through a known common derived class:

```cpp
int main() {
    UserComponent userComponent = UserComponent();
    EventE* ptrEventE = static_cast<EventE*>(&userComponent);
    Component* ptrComponent = static_cast<UserComponent*>(ptrEventE);  // UserComponent --> Component is implicit
    cout << ptrComponent->customValue << endl;
}
```